# Integrating bootsrap 5 in Nuxt 3 and Vite

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-5, vite

I'm trying to integrate Bootstrap 5 in a new Nuxt 3 project but I'm facing a problem that I cannot solve : I want to optimise it by importing only the necessary modules (both scss and javascript) as explained here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/.

I successfully imported the style but I cannot find a proper way to import the necessary js.
I have created a `bootstrap.js` file in the `public` directory as following :

```
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/button';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/carousel';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tab';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/toast';
// import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
```

And added this file in the meta section of nuxt.config.ts to make sure the file is called in the head section of my page so the javascript is available everywhere

```
meta: {
    script: [
        { src: 'js/bootstrap.js' }
    ],
}
```

But I keep having an error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I understand it is because Vite does not compile it, but I don't know how to make it do so.. has someone an idea how to do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 23):

1. **yarn add bootstrap**
2. Create **plugins/useBootstrap.client.ts** file and paste the following code

---

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.provide('bootstrap', bootstrap)
})
```

---

3. Run this command **yarn add --dev sass sass-loader@latest**
4. Create **assets/styles/main.scss** file and paste following code

---

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

---

5. Add the following code in **nuxt.config.ts**

---

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss'],
})
```

---

6. If you want to use the js-dependent content like dropdown, modals then you have to install **yarn add --dev @popperjs/core** OR **npm install --save @popperjs/core**

---

**Note:** You can customize the bootstrap in the main.scss file

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did not need step 2 for this to work. I don't think `sass-loader` is required in step 3 if you use vite (the default and also mentioned in the question) and not webpack.

Comment: Just letting you know for upcoming people, the above setup is not working for components that require the Javascript files. Still trying to figure. Will be happy if anyone found that. Thanks

Comment: @Javaid Thanks, Did you find a way for importing components(Eg: Modal, Toast, etc..,)?

Comment: we have a complaint from intellij as dist folder not exist : could not find declaration module for 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'

Comment: js not working with this way

Comment: This is working fine, except plugin part: `import * as twbs from 'bootstrap' export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => { nuxtApp.provide('bootstrap', twbs) })`

Comment: Excelent! I have used npm instead of yarn and had success

Answer (score 3):

Here an example with bootstrap5 and Nuxtjs3 (css and js), popper is not required as include in Bundle (tested) and Jquery no longer required.

```
yarn install bootstrap5
```

then create in plugins directory file

"useBootstrap.client.ts"

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            bootstrap: bootstrap
        }
    }
})
```

then you can import css in scss file or directly in (i made both)

"nuxt.config.ts"

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css","~/assets/styles/main.scss"],
    
})
```

You can directly add component, modal, dropdown etc, if you want to exclude some imports, do it in the plugin file.

Answer (score 2):

if you have not solved yet, try this way. It works for me.

1. Install bootstrap5

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

2. Change the nuxt config settings (nuxt.config.ts)

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"], // add
  vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.DEBUG": false,
    },
  },
});
```

3. See if the styles is applied. (app.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="m-5">
    <!-- <NuxtPage /> -->
    <div class="btn btn-success">Success</div>
    <div class="btn btn-danger">Danger</div>
    <div class="btn btn-warning">Warning</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import necessary bootstrap js in a client-side project.

`plugins/bootstrap.client.ts`

```js
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => ({
  provide: {
    bootstrap: {
      Modal,
    },
  },
}));
```

`app.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="toggle()">toggle modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-main">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="max-width: 600px">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Hello world!</h5>
            <button
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body p-4">Hello bootstrap and nuxt</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Modal } from "bootstrap";
const { $bootstrap } = useNuxtApp();

let modal: Modal;
onMounted(() => {
  modal = new $bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("modal-main"));
});

const toggle = () => {
  modal.toggle();
};
</script>
```

this is a sample project, which includes only the necessary styles and js for bootstrap modal, about 60KB on first screen loading.

https://github.com/Debonex/samples/tree/master/nuxt3-bootstrap5

Comment: the problem with this solution is we have to execute manually action automatised with bootsrap 5 and data-target toggle etc

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Bootstrap,

   ```
   npm install bootstrap
   ```
2. Config `nuxt.config.ts`,

   ```
   export default defineNuxtConfig({
     css: [
       'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
     ],
     script: [
       {
         src: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
       }
     ],
     vite: {
       define: {
         'process.env.DEBUG': false,
       },
     },
   })
   ```

Comment: on nuxt3 script is not working because script is not a part of child of the config

Answer (score 1):

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"], // add
  vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.DEBUG": false,
    },
  },

  app: {
    head: {
      script: [
        {
          src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          type: "text/javascript",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

please copy this code in the file nuxt.config.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you are prototyping and want to include the CDNs, try this in your `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        head: {
            link: [
                {
                    rel: 'stylesheet',
                    href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    integrity: 'sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD',
                    crossorigin: 'anonymous'
                }
            ],
            script: [
                {
                    src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
                    integrity: 'sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN',
                    crossorigin: 'anonymous'
                }
            ],
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There still seem to be a lot of people having trouble getting bootstrap 5 to run in Nuxt 3 so first of as reference here is a starter project that has it all running:

https://github.com/maxvanweenen/Nuxt-3-bootstrap-5-starter

Most people get bootstrap 5 css to work, but not the JS. The most important step to get this working is including both bootstrap and Popper in your installation:

```
npm i --save bootstrap @popperjs/core
```

and then registering it as a plugin by making a 'plugins' directory in the root of your project and adding a file like 'useBootstrap.client.ts' (the 'client' part will tell Nuxt to not use this on the server side).

```
// useBootstrap.client.ts    
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            bootstrap: bootstrap
        }
    }
})
```

Now you only need to add the css to the nuxt config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss'
]
```

})

And create a main.scss within assets/scss.

Some extra important information:

Installation of fibers is not mentioned in bootstrap documentation but synchronous compilation with sass (2x speed increase) is enabled automatically when fibers is installed. so it is recommended to run:

```
npm install fibers
```

Also if you want to customise or add theme colors in this setup you will do that like this:

```
// set theme colors
$primary: #ce2127;
$dark: #212121;
$theme1: #33a8d1;

// add custom colors to the bootstrap theme
$custom-theme-colors: (
        "theme1": $theme1,
        "white": $white
);

// fix for bootstrap transposing colors
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
```

If anybody has still any trouble getting it to run after this let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Share and Voted

1. using cdn with app head

```
  

      app: {
            head: {
       
              link: [
                {
                  rel: "stylesheet",
                  href: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                  integrity: "sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD",
                  crossorigin: "anonymous"
                }
              ],
              script: [
                {
                  src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                  integrity: "sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3",
                  crossorigin: "anonymous"
                },
                {
                  src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                  integrity: "sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD",
                  crossorigin: "anonymous"
                }
              ]
        
            },
          },
```

2. OR dowload css and js bootstrap to public folder/bootstrap and using in head.

```
 

app: {
    head: {
      title: 'My awesome project', // Other meta information
      link:[
        {
          rel: "stylesheet",
          href: "bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
        }
      ],
      script: [
        {
          src: "bootstrap/popper.min.js",
          crossorigin: "anonymous"
        },
        {
          src: "bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
          crossorigin: "anonymous"
        }
      ]

    }
 }
```