# Nuxt 3 - adding script.js into nuxt.config error

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3

test.js always throws this error in console  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' test.js:1`. (test.js) is completely empty.

but if I replace ~/asssets/js/test.js with some random CDN (https://www.gimmiecdn.com) this has no errors and runs correctly.

this also works

`script: [{ children: "console.log('Hello, world!');" }]`

css - works correctly too

Suggestions please.

```
//nuxt.config.ts

import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'
import {resolve} from "path";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
 app: {
    head: {
      htmlAttrs: { lang: "en" },
      title:'title',
      charset: 'utf-8',
      meta:[
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' 

      }],
      script: [
        { 
          src: "~/assets/js/test.js",
        },
      ],
    }, 
  },
  css: ["~/assets/styles/scss/main.scss"],

  ssr:true,


});
```

**Edit:**

[Integrating bootsrap 5 in Nuxt 3 and Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099682/integrating-bootsrap-5-in-nuxt-3-and-vite)

I just found this here on stack looking into something else. Maybe this is the reason? They are trying to include a script using nuxt.config thats not a CDN like me.. But i'm not sure what the guys comment means.

//config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  ],
  script: [
    {
      src: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
    }
  ],
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
})
```

And the comment someone left

```
on nuxt3 script is not working because script is not a part of child of the config
```

**A SOLUTION** but.. it doesn't explain or solve the issue. I'll circle back if I found out why /js doesn't work in the assets folder.

Move .js into /public then in app.vue add script to **useHead()** function

```
//app.vue
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <TopBar/>
  <LeftSideBar />
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
useHead({
  title: 'title',
  meta: [
    { name: 'description', content: 'My amazing site.' }
  ],
  script: [
        { 
          src: "/js/test.js",
          body:true
         }
      ],
});
</script>
```

Or if you want to change nuxt.config.

I couldn't get **body:true** to work inside defineNuxtConfig(). And I needed script to load at body of page so i used useHead()

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
 app: {
    head: {
      htmlAttrs: { lang: "en" },
      title:'title',
      charset: 'utf-8',
      meta:[
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' 

      }],
     script:[{src:'/js/test.js'}]

      
    }, 
  }
 })
```